# iOS Swift UIScrollView dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm facing some problems while trying to calculate the height of a scrollView. I've made a "test" app to underline the problem.
I just have a controller which is embedded in a NavigationController which is embedded itself in a TabBarController.

Then I have a view on the top of the screen and a scrollView just under this view containing 2 labels. I'm trying to calculate the height of the scrollView by getting the biggest maxY among its subviews. Here is the code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // I have to add this line so that the red view doesn't show under the navigation bar
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.maxY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - view.frame.maxY))
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    label1.text = "test"
    label1.sizeToFit()
    scrollView.addSubview(label1)

    let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 700, width: 0, height: 0))
    label2.text = "test"
    label2.sizeToFit()
    scrollView.addSubview(label2)

    // Calculate scrollView height
    var maxY:CGFloat = 0
    for view in scrollView.subviews {
        if view.frame.maxY > maxY {
            maxY = view.frame.maxY
        }
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: maxY)

    self.view.addSubview(view)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
}
```

So this is what I have:

[image]

I should see the other "test" label at the bottom when scrolling but it's not the case, the scrollView is not big enough

If I remove the red view, make the scrollView fits all the main view and remove this line
`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None`
then it works :

[image]

Any solution ?